# Configure docker volumes to share data across host and containers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ssl, docker-compose

I am stuck trying to configure docker volumes to share files between my host and make able in my container to use this files. let me explain.

I have a rails docker app with puma as a web server, I want to make able to puma to view and use the ssl .key and .crt files, so for this project also I am using docker-compose in "production mode", but I do not know how to make this work.

My setup is this:

- Ubuntu 18.04 server host for production has the ssl files inside `/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys`, the containers are also in my host.

**/home/ubuntu/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.5
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_DB: my_app_production
    env_file:
      -~/production.env

  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.11

  web:
    image: my_app:latest
    command: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys/server.key&cert=/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys/server.crt' -e production
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/my_app_keys
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ~/production.env
    restart: always

  sidekiq:
    image: my_app_sidekiq:latest
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ~/production.env
    restart: always
```

so, as you can see: `command: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys/server.key&cert=/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys/server.crt'` is looking for ssl files in /home/ubuntu/my_app_keys, when I execute `docker-compose up` puma can not find the ssl files and exits with:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/minissl.rb:180:in `key=': No such key file '/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys/server.key' (ArgumentError)
```

I think is because `key=/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys/server.key&cert=/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys/server.crt` are pointing in the container context but I have the cert and key in my host context

so, I include in docker compose volume in order to bind-mount the files:

```
volumes:
  - /home/ubuntu/my_app_keys
```

but without luck, same error.

In the container context my app lives in `/var/www/my_app` directory, so I tried to specify an absolute path (for some reason I imagined that it was because the ssl files were not in the same directory where my app lived could not be shared), so I add as [compose-file docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) say:

```
volumes:
  - /home/ubuntu/my_app_keys:/var/www/my_app
```

and change in compose file:

```
command: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=server.key&cert=server.crt' -e
```

when I execute the compose up my web service exit with error:

```
web | Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

only way that web service run is (but no ssl files exist):

```
volumes:
  - /home/ubuntu/my_app_keys
```

so, I do not know what to do now. any help?

Answer (score 1):

When your Docker Compose YAML file says:

```
volumes:
  - /home/ubuntu/my_app_keys
```

It means, "make `/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys` in container space persist across restarts of the container; it will start off empty unless the Dockerfile did something special; it's not connected to any specific host content".

When you say:

```
volumes:
  - /home/ubuntu/my_app_keys:/var/www/my_app
```

It means, "totally replace the contents of `/var/www/my_app` in container space with the contents of `/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys` on the host".  (The path names in host and container space don't need to be the same.)

As a bonus question, when you say:

```
rails server -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?...'
```

It means, "only listen for inbound connections on port 3000 initiated from within this Docker container; don't accept any connections from outside the container at all, whether from the same physical host, other containers, or elsewhere."

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation, I changed volumes to `/home/ubuntu/my_app_keys:/var/www/my_app/ssl` and also changed `rails server -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?...'` as puma server documentation says 0.0.0.0 default. but no luck, I am unable to see .key and .crt files in container in path .../my_app/ssl